# Combobox sender SelectionChanged Event C#

Tags: c#, combobox, selectionchanged

So this code worked perfectly fine for another `ComboBox`, but even though I changed everything in the code the way it should be it refuses to work now - Different `ComboBox`, different source but you know ignoring that it is the same situation.

The code that's in the `ComboBox`'s `Selectionchanged` Event:

```
ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
string id = comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

It is throwing:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

On the line with the Selected Value.

Comment: very unclear what is unclear about it. ;P

Comment: what exactly you want to do?

Comment: It's better if you show other codes even error is from this line of codes.

Comment: When you start typing in the textbox of a ComboBox that has DropDownStyle = DropDown then the SelectionChanged event will fire.  Because the selection changed, there is *no* selection anymore.  You therefore need to check if SelectedValue is null to avoid the NRE.

Answer (score 1):

try below

```
ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
if(comboBox!=null  && comboBox.SelectedValue != null){ 
      string id = comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

need to check related other codes to find why `SelectedValue` is null.

Comment: if `comboBox` be `null` then checking `comboBox.SelectedValue != null` will not throw an exception?

Comment: if comboBox null then it will not check the next condition because here we have `and` operator